# How am I meant to release an array returned from a class method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a section of my code which calls a method returning an `NSMutableArray` like so:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)method {

NSMutableArray *rgb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:....., nil];

    return rgb;

}
```

It gives me a leak every time it's called. Putting `[rgb release];` after `return` doesn't appear to work. Putting it before `return` makes my app crash. Also putting in an `autorelease` makes my app crash. Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
+(NSMutableArray *)method {
    NSMutableArray *rgb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:....., nil];
    return [rgb autorelease];
}
```

Alternatively:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)method {
    NSMutableArray *rgb = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:....., nil];
    return rgb;
}
```

IF this still crashes, then the problem is most likely outside of that method, not within.

Comment: Both of these cause a crash. Not sure what the solution is. It just won't let me release the array anywhere without causing problems. Any other possible solutions? It's either that or have leaking objects, which as you know isn't an option either.

Comment: I think you're leaking not the array itself, but some object(s) inside it.

Comment: Here's the array in full: `NSMutableArray *rgb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:redInt],[NSNumber numberWithInt:greenInt],[NSNumber numberWithInt:blueInt], nil];`

Comment: This is absolutely fine. As I said, it's most likely an issue outside the method. Are you by any chance doing something like this `[[yourClass method] autorelease];`? (Which would add the array to the autorelease pool twice)

Comment: Maybe you're releasing those objects.

Comment: The object was being released outside the method, which was causing the crash. I've removed that now. However, using the [rgb autorelease] i'm still getting the same leak.

Comment: The leak is definitely not caused by the method itself though, given that it matches the snippet you posted. Search your code for excessive retails, run Analyze, run Instruments.

Answer (score 4):

> But this gives me a leak every time
>   it's called. Putting a [rgb release];
>   after return doesn't appear to work.
>   putting it before return makes my app
>   crash. Also putting in an autorelease
>   makes my app crash. Suggestions?

You need to read the [Cocoa Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).  It makes it quite clear that such a method as that must autorelease the returned object:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)method {
    NSMutableArray *rgb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:....., nil];

    return [rgb autorelease];
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)method {
    NSMutableArray *rgb = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:....., nil];

    return rgb;
}
```

An over-retain (like in your code) will not cause a crash (at least not until you run out of memory).  If you have a crash, it is most likely because your are mismanaging memory in other ways.

Try using Build and Analyze and fixing all of the issues it identifies.  If it still crashes, post the backtrace of the crash if you can't figure out why.

Comment: I tried both methods and it gave me a bad access crash, leading me to main.m.

Comment: Yes -- no surprise -- you have a bug somewhere else.  The two implementations I showed are correct.  You are likely over-releasing the object elsewhere.